# How to get the pathname of url with no path

Tags: javascript

Good Day

I am using this function to get the pathname of the current window:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;

if(pathname == '/someDir'){
   do something
}
```

Now what do you do if you have no path ie: http://mydomain.com ?

Now what I can do is the following:

```
var hostname = document.location.hostname;

if(hostname == 'mydomain.com'){
   do something on the home page only!;
}
```

BUT the issue with the code above is that it will execute on all pages since the hostname is contained everywhere... ie mydomain.com/contact

**So how do I target the home page ("mydomain.com") ONLY?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var hostname = document.location.hostname;
var pathname = document.location.pathname;

if(hostname == 'mydomain.com' && pathname == '/'){
   do something on the home page only!;
}
```

You'll notice that I added a check for the `pathname` to equal '/'. That will be your home page, unless you've configured your server otherwise.

You might also want to check for a pathname of `'/index.htm'` (or whatever your index file is, if any) in the event that a user ends up there.

Comment: Thank you, but my home page url is just of format: mydomain.com, with nou trailing '/' or anything...

Comment: The forward slash *should* still work. If you're sure that won't work, however, try replacing `pathname == '/'` with just `!pathname`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be stating the obvious but how about

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
if (pathname === "/") {
  do something on the home page only!;
}
```

There should not be any reason to check the hostname as your code will only be executed on your own domain, 'mydomain.com'.

Comment: you see, my landing page/homepage does not have a trailing /

Comment: That should not matter, if I am not mistaken then `window.location.pathname` will return `"/"` even if there is no trailing slash (at least it does for me on Chrome).